# Functions composition - Unreadable result

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, education

I tried to evaluate the following composite function:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[1 - x^2], x <= 1},
   {x, x >= 1}}]
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{x + 1, x >= 0},
   {x^2, x < 0}}]
Composition[f, g][x]
```

the result is:

[image]

I have some difficulty reading it. What does it mean and is it possible to write it in a simple way?

---

EDIT: the result of the command `Composition[f, g][x] // FullSimplify` is

[image]

it seems that this is a wrong result; the right one is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4365986/composition-of-piecewise-functions-strange-result?noredirect=1#comment9127033_4365986

Comment: Yeah, just use `Composition[f, g][x] // FullSimplify` and you'll get a single piecewise result. `// PiecewiseExpand` also works but gives a slightly more complex answer with an additional entry.

Comment: Hello @flinty thank you for your suggestion. I got a result different from the right one which is reported here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4365986/composition-of-piecewise-functions-strange-result?noredirect=1#comment9127033_4365986

Comment: The definitions of $f$ differ: Here it has $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and there it has $\sqrt{1-x}$.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you very much, I miss that point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The results are the same.

```
fg[x_] = Composition[f, g][x];
fgs[x_] = FullSimplify[fg[x]];
Plot[{f[g[x]], fg[x] + 1, fgs[x] + 2}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]
(constants added to separate the lines)

```
Simplify[f[g[x]] == fg[x] == fgs[x]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Hello @JohnDoty I mean that the result of Mathematica is different from the result in the link I posted.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi How does it differ? Clearly, we have three representations of `f[g[x]]` which are equal. No doubt there are more.

Comment: for example here there isn't sqrt(1 - x^4). https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4365986/composition-of-piecewise-functions-strange-result?noredirect=1#comment9127033_4365986

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi But is your example equivalent? What does `Simplify[ your example, f[g[x]]` say?

Comment: I made a mistake in the question because there is x^2 instead of x.